# Métodos para testar sites em navegadores diferentes?

Tags: html, testes

Gostaria de saber métodos para testar sites em diferentes navegadores, sem a criação de virtual machines.

Answer (score 13):

Encontrei o site [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com) que é uma ferramenta de testes *cross-browser*. Ele possui diferentes plataformas, navegadores e versões de navegadores, me ajudou bastante.

O serviço é pago e a versão *trial* é limitada a 30 minutos *Live*, 100 minutos de *Automate* e 100 capturas de tela mais *Responsive*.

Comment: A versão gratuita possui 30 minutos de teste!

Comment: É mais barato aprender a usar VirtualBox ou VMWare e virtualizar o desenvolvimento.

Comment: Mas o que me interessou foi o teste com dispositivos mobiles, com diversos dispositivos e OS.

Answer (score 7):

Em uma máquina você já pode aproveitar pra usar vários navegadores, outra solução é o www.browserstack.com. Eu uso VM para testar, até onde experimentei é o método mais fácil.

Answer (score 7):

Primeiramente eu não testaria todos os browsers, e nem me preocuparia com testar no máximo possível de browsers, mas sim nos browsers mais importantes para o público alvo. Para se ter uma ideia do quanto os browsers são usados, eu uso o [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#all-browser_version_partially_combined-BR-monthly-201302-201402), que mostra gráficos como abaixo:

[image: StatCounter]

Dependendo do browser eu não testaria outras versões, e teria sempre a versão mais recente instalada, como é o caso do Google Chrome e do FireFox que se atualizam sozinhos. Teria também versões dos outros navegadores instalados, sendo os principais, o Safari e o Opera. E finalmente o IE, teria instalada a última versão, que permite simular as versões antigas, desde a 8 ou 7.

Se precisar de testar em versões mais antigas do IE ou do FireFox, poderia usar o [Utilu IE Collection](http://utilu.com/IECollection/) e o [Utilu FireFox Collection](http://utilu.com/UtiluMFC/).

Para testar outros sistemas operacionais, ai eu criaria máquinas virtuais usando o [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), e faria com que rodassem o mais leve o possível... só com navegador mesmo.

Além disso, vale a pena conferir o site [www.modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie/en-us), que contém informações sobre como testar vários navegadores.

Comment: Google é Google, nem vem falar que Firefox é melhor,  choro livre :)

Answer (score 4):

Para testar em dispositivos móveis a melhor solução que conheço é o serviço **EDGE** da Adobe

[Try EDGE](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/)

Answer (score 4):

Para esse tipo de teste eu uso o **[Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/)**. Tem uma versão gratuita dele **[aqui](http://sahi.co.in/sahi-open-source/)**. Nele os testes são scripts que você pode criar "gravando macros" (como no MS-Office) ou então redigindo os scripts na mão, numa sintaxe bem simples. Depois é só rodar os testes em qualquer navegador. Funciona bem.

Você também pode tentar o Selenium, que é outra ferramenta similar.

Answer (score 3):

Fiz uma lista aqui com vários que uso e recomendo:

- [Browser Stack](http://www.browserstack.com/)
- [Browserling](https://browserling.com/)

Pra debugar em diferentes devices e testar sites responsivos:

- [Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/)
- [Ghostlab](http://vanamco.com/ghostlab/)
- [Remote
  Preview](http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/remote-preview/)
- [Opera
  Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/pt-br/developer/mobile-emulator)

E tem essas VMs para o VM Ware, pra quem precisa testar em várias versões de IE:

- [IEVMS](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms)

Quem usa grunt pode usar o Browser Sync, se você acessar o site pelo seu IP em diferentes dispositivos, ele sincroniza a navegação, atualiza o CSS sem dar refresh e sincroniza ações de formulário, digitação e rolagem. Bem legal! * 
[Browser Sync](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/)

Aqui segue um outro link, muito útil:

- [Responsive Design Tools](http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/resources.html)